# There is a % sign after my result in the terminal, while using C

Tags: c

I am very new to programming. After a brief introduction to C, I was following a tutorial for a simple calculator.

This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    char operator;
    double num1;
    double num2;
    double result;

    printf("\nEnter an operator (+ - * /): ");
    scanf("%c", &operator);

    printf("Enter number 1: ");
    scanf("%lf", &num1);

    printf("Enter number 2: ");
    scanf("%lf", &num2);

    switch(operator){
        case '+':
            result = num1 + num2;
            printf("\nresult: %.2lf", result);
            break;

        case '-':
            result = num1 - num2;
            printf("\nresult: %.2lf", result);
            break;

        case '*':
            result = num1 * num2;
            printf("\nresult: %.2lf", result);
            break;

        case '/':
            result = num1 / num2;
            printf("\nresult: %.2lf", result);
            break;
            
        default:
            printf("%c is not valid", operator);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Everything is working properly, except that I am getting a '%' sign after the result. [Image of the result I am getting in the terminal.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5NAzK.png) What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for the help.

Comment: You're not supposed to put `\n` in front of the string, it's supposed to be at the end.

Answer (score 3):

It's your shell's prompt.

Print a line feed (`"\n"`) after your output to push it to the next line.